# Sql syntax Error number 1064

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
$Sql ="
    UPDATE 
        pick_up_address
    SET 
        user_id                 = '" . $movers_id . "',
        member_group_id         = '" . $member_group_id . "',
        nick_name               = '" . $_POST[' nick_name '][$i] . "',
        contact_person_name     = '" . $_POST[' contact_person_name '][$i] . "',
        contact_person_number   = '" . $_POST[' contact_person_number '][$i] . "',
        contact_address         = '" . $_POST[' contact_address '][$i] . "'
    WHERE
        pick_up_address_id      = '" . $pick_adddress_id[$i] . "',
        lat                     = '" . $lat1 . "',
        lng                     = '" . $lng1 . "'";
```

Error Message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near lat="value", lng="value"

Comment: You cannot concatenate WHERE clauses by commas, you have to use operators like AND or OR. So: .. WHERE pick_up_address_id='".$pick_adddress_id[$i]."' AND lat='".$lat1."' ...`

Comment: @arkascha - you should write this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate WHERE clauses by commas as you are trying to in your code snippet. Instead you have to use operators like AND or OR.

So instead of

```
... WHERE pick_up_address_id='".$pick_adddress_id[$i]."', lat='".$lat1."' ...`
```

try something like

```
... WHERE pick_up_address_id='".$pick_adddress_id[$i]."' AND lat='".$lat1."' ...`
```

The syntax for such `WHERE` clauses is precisely defined in the mysql documentation, though actually this is just standard SQL syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html